# Passing LLVM Assembly into GHC

Tags: haskell

I've passed ".cmm" files into GHC and called C-- functions from my my ".hs" file via a foreign import. I'd like to instead pass LLVM assembly files and similarly call functions in them. I would then assume the LLVM compiler would put both of these files together, generating nice machine code. Is this possible with GHC, and if so how? Answer here with simple example or link to a documentation or tutorial is fine.

Comment: What have you tried? It looks from the GHC source like you should be able to just give a `.ll` file on the command line and it will be compiled and linked with the rest of your program or library.